# N is a four digit number. If the leftmost digit is removed, the resulting three digit number is 1/9th of N. How many such N are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

N is a four digit number. If the leftmost digit is
removed, the resulting three digit number is
1/9th of N. How many such N are possible with solution?

Comment: tell me possible numbers it can form??

Comment: For future reference please put your questions in greater context than merely copying the problem statement.  Why is this problem of interest to you?  If you tried to solve it, explain what you tried and what results or difficulties were found.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in[1,9]$ denote the leftmost digit.

Let $y\in[000,999]$ denote the remaining digits.

$1000x+y=9y\implies1000x=8y\implies125x=y$.

---

Hence there are $7$ possible values of $N$:

- $x=\color\red{1} \implies y=\color\green{ 125} \implies N=\color\red{1}\color\green{ 125}$
- $x=\color\red{2} \implies y=\color\green{ 250} \implies N=\color\red{2}\color\green{ 250}$
- $x=\color\red{3} \implies y=\color\green{ 375} \implies N=\color\red{3}\color\green{ 375}$
- $x=\color\red{4} \implies y=\color\green{ 500} \implies N=\color\red{4}\color\green{ 500}$
- $x=\color\red{5} \implies y=\color\green{ 625} \implies N=\color\red{5}\color\green{ 625}$
- $x=\color\red{6} \implies y=\color\green{ 750} \implies N=\color\red{6}\color\green{ 750}$
- $x=\color\red{7} \implies y=\color\green{ 875} \implies N=\color\red{7}\color\green{ 875}$

---

In the remaining cases, $y\not\in[000,999]$:

- $x=\color\red{8} \implies y=\color\green{1000}$
- $x=\color\red{9} \implies y=\color\green{1125}$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we consider the four digit number $N$ as "$abcd$", i.e.,

\begin{eqnarray}
N=1000a+100b+10c+d.
\end{eqnarray}

We are given

\begin{align}
\frac{1000a+100b+10c+d}{9}&=(100b+10c+d)\\
\Rightarrow 125a-100b-10c-d=0.
\end{align}

This allows $a$ to vary from $1-7$, and the resulting numbers are $1125,2250,3375,4500,5625,6750,$ and $7875$.

Comment: Sir in question the left most digit is been removed..

Comment: @Manoj Yes. That is what I have used in the question. For example, if we take $1125$, upon removing the leftmost digit, we are left with $125$, which is $1/9^{th}$ of $1125$.

Comment: why a is not 8 ?

Comment: possible answer given are 10, 9, 8, 7.. in the question paper. which is the correct answer with explanation?

Comment: As @barak has pointed out in the answer below, for $a=8$, we get $N=9000$, and removing the last digit gives $000$, which is certainly not $1/9^{th}$ of $9000$. For $a=9$, we get a five digit number.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$ \begin{align*} 1000a+100b+10c+d=9(100b+10c+d) &\iff 1000a=800b+80c+8d \\ &\iff125a=100b+10c+d=bcd \end{align*} $$

The answer is clearly given by all the values of the digit $a$ such that $125a$ have three digits, then there are seven possibilities ($a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ are good; $a=0$ $a=8,9$ must be discarded).

Comment: @Hardmath: thank you very much for a double serving: My answer has been centered properly and also I have learned something useful from TeX Commands.

Comment: The `align*` environment is useful in many ways.  Check out the [Mathjax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some interesting uses.

Comment: I will do it. Thanks again.